# Missing Expression in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle11g

can i know why am i getting missing expression, is there any wrong with this statement.

```
    select *  
    from 
    (
       select student_id, attendance_day, attendance_id
       from attendance
    ) src
    pivot
    (
      sum(attendance_id)
      for attendance_day in ([to_date('23-Oct-2016', 'DD-Mon-YYYY')],                                         [to_date('24-Oct-2016', 'DD-Mon-YYYY')])
    ) piv;
```

Comment: You need to use the same column in `sum()` that appears after the `for` restriction.

Comment: Can you show us sample data and your desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line

```
for attendance_day in ([to_date('23-Oct-2016', 'DD-Mon-YYYY')],                                         [to_date('24-Oct-2016', 'DD-Mon-YYYY')])
```

to

```
 for attendance_day in (to_date('23-Oct-2016', 'DD-Mon-YYYY'),to_date('24-Oct-2016', 'DD-Mon-YYYY'))
```